# Crear html mientras se ejecuta javascript

Tags: javascript

Tengo un problema estoy creando un juego sencillo y me ha surgido un problema, el juego es un ahorcado típico, tengo una función principal para manejar todo os la dejo:

```
    function jugar() {
        if (numIntentos == null) { // Si el numero de intento esta vacío inicia el juego
            pedirPalabra(); // Pide palabra para jugar y lo convierte en Array
            prepararPalabra(palabraSecreta); // Crea un Array con * para jugar con el
            mostrarTablero(); // Muestra el pablero con la palabra con * y los intentos
            pedirLetra(); // Solicita una letra para evaluar
        } else {
            console.log("no esta vacio");
        }
    }

/* -------------------- Funcion para preparar el tablero -------------------- */
function mostrarTablero() {
    // Mensaje de intentos
    let elemento = document.createElement('h2');
    elemento.innerHTML = `
    Te queden ${numIntentos} intentos, suerte!!
    `;
    tablero.appendChild(elemento);
    for (let i = 0; i < palabraOculta.length; i++) {
        let elemento = document.createElement('span');
        elemento.innerHTML = `
        <input type="text" readonly="true" name="letra" value="${palabraOculta[i]}"
        style="width: 75px; text-align:center; font-weight: bold; font-size: 1.3rem;
        line-height: 2.5">
        `;
        tablero.appendChild(elemento)
    }    
}
```

Pero tengo un problema, cuando llamo mostrar tablero para dibujar, no se ejecuta, sino que que antes se ejecuta pedir letra que esta después, y una vez introduzco la letra se dibuja. Como podría solucionarlo

Comment: Habría que ver el código de `mostrarTablero()` es probable que tengas llamadas a procesos asíncronos.

Comment: ¿Usas `prompt()` en la función `pedirLetra()`? Probablemente ese es el problema, algunos navegadores actualizan el DOM hasta que se "resuelve" el resultado de esa ventana. La solución sería crear un _input_ para introducir la letra o, si lo quieres más vistoso, botones que simulen un teclado.